# How to chance or rewrite a csv row

Tags: python, function, csv, row

I' doing a small project for the coursework and i get struggle with this , gonna show u now:
[A code that i find on the internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Xfr.png)
And [the csv file (focus on playcount)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YYZ2.png)
And the def that i created in other python to using the playcount change function[Play playlist button fucntion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LKpn.png)

My problem is seem like my code is not working and i don't how, it suppose to run perfectly but my playcount didn't increate when i click the play playlist button[this is a GUI of the play playlist function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLY1B.png)
I think maybe my def update_play_count is wrong nut i don't know why is that.